# I want to save response from api and re_used with next request from user in php laravel framework ..without save to database?

Tags: php, laravel, api, controller, response

```
$response = Http::withHeaders($headers)->post($URL, $postdata);
```

Comment: You need to elaborate your question further. On which framework are you? Post some more codes so that we can understand what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: So after you receive the response, what do you want to do with the response? You want to use it in some other function? Or just want to use it with the next request from the user? Then you can store the response in session and retrieve it back from session on the next request..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: want to use it with the next request from the user? Then you can store the response in session and retrieve it back from session on the next request.??how  can be stored in session and called it??

Answer (score 1):

Just save the response in session, example:

```
Session::put('sessionName', $response);
```

And if you want to call it you can use :

```
Session::get('sessionName');
```

Comment: I did this code but I want to called  session in another function how ??

Comment: how I can,t send session from function to another function??

Comment: Do you have to try `Session::get('sessionName')` in other function??

Comment: yes I tried ,but returned null

Comment: can you send your code, please

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Here are some possibilities.

If you are using the frontend frameworks such as vue.js/ React.js you can use their feature to remember the state.

Other possible option:

1. If you are using core JS or Jquery and   ajax/axios to request. you can declare a global variable in javascript and store in that variable which you can use inside the same page until your page refresh,
2. If you are getting data refreshing the page you can use Session as @Ezha suggested.
3. If you just want to reduce database transaction, it is fine to request multiple, you can cache your query in controller using Laravel query cache feature.